# Coarea formula in general manifolds- evaluation of an integral

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold (without boundary) and $p\in M$ be fixed. I am trying to evaluate(or find an upper bound) of the following integral:

$$
\int_{x\in M \setminus B(p,1)} \mbox{dist}(x,p)^\alpha \ dV(x).
$$

Of course, for it to be finite, we may need to impose some conditions on $\alpha$. In Euclidean space, we can use the coarea formula to do this.
I do not know how this can be done in general manifolds. Any kind of answers, references, hints are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, that is not the difficulty I am having. Let me edit the question, so  that my exact problem would be clearer.

Comment: The coarea formula on a Riemannian manifold is essentially the same as for Euclidean space. If the differential of a smooth function is always nonzero and therefore its level sets  are smooth hypersurfaces, then the argument presented here can be adapted easily to a Riemannian manifold. https://deaneyang.github.io/blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/integration/2021/07/09/CoareaFormula.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. But I could not understand how that can be applied to evaluate the integral in the question. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, we know the exact relation between the surface areas of the boundaries of two balls of different radii. Can we say something like this here also?

Comment: Are you assuming $M$ is compact or open and complete? What range of $\alpha$ are you interested in?

Comment: I suggest studying the proof of the Bishop-Gromov inequality, as well as work on estimating the volume of a tubular neighborhood of a hypersurface. One paper you could look at is by Heintze and Karcher These all involve estimating volume, but their arguments should be useful for your integral, too.

Comment: @Deane I am interested in the non-compact setting with $\alpha<0$. However, completeness can be assumed. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Any assumptions about curvature or volume growth of geodesic balls?

Comment: I was trying to do it for general manifolds. Solutions for any particular case would be of interest to me. Also if I'd like to see if the range of  $\alpha$ changes as we take different manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the coarea formula, since in this case it just says that if $V(r) = V(B(p,r))$, then $V'(r)$ is the surface area of $\partial B(p,r)$. Here's a suggestion:

If I understand correctly, you are trying to estimate
\begin{align*}
\int_{x\in M\backslash B(p,1)} (d(x,p))^\alpha\,dV(x)
&= \int_{r=1}^{r=R} r^\alpha V_{n-1}(\partial B(p,r))\,dr.
\end{align*}
Therefore, any estimate on the surface area of a geodesic sphere implies a bound on the integral. It might also be useful to integrate by parts,
\begin{align*}
\int_{r=1}^{r=R} r^\alpha V_{n-1}(\partial B(p,r))\,dr
&= \int_{r=1}^{r=R} r^\alpha V'(r)\,dr\\
&= R^\alpha V(R) - V(1) - \alpha\int_{r=1}^{r=R} r^{\alpha-1}V(r)\,dr
\end{align*}
and derive an estimate from estimates on the volume growth of geodesic balls.

Comment: Thank you @Deane. That was very helpful.